# How to compile vue.js and tailwind.js for IE11 on Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, babeljs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to run **vue.js** and **tailwind.js** on **IE11** but without any success. Chrome, Firefox and Safari are fine.

Is there any possiblity to compile the .js and .css files for IE11 so that it looks the same as the other Internet browsers ?

What I have tried:

added babel to mix in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .babel('public/js/app.js', 'public/js/es5js.js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .tailwind('./tailwind.config.js')
  .version();
```

on my main site I'm loading it with `<script src="{{ mix('/js/es5js.js') }}"></script>`

but the style and javascript are still not loading correctly. It seems that there are not at all loaded.

It looks like this:

[image]

and how it should look like:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Mix already uses babel compilation with .js, so you should remove the separate .babel call:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .tailwind('./tailwind.config.js')
   .version();
```

And then in your view:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

To configure the browsers, use browserlist (https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist). I think it's already working out of the box with laravel mix.

Example of .browserslistrc File:

```
# Browsers that we support 

last 1 version
> 1%
IE 11
maintained node versions
not dead
```

And here is a good link for browserlist and browser-usage: https://browserl.ist

Comment: I'm new to the whole compilation world. Your solution is not working. Vue components are still not loading on IE11.

Comment: @Greg Ostry keep focusing on vue+ IE11, that's a whole separate problem. See what others in the world have found as a solution (besides dropping support for IE11)